# Parent component state change is not detected by child component when using redux-form and connect

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

Parent component state change is not detected by child component when using redux-form and connect but when you edit someother field then it populates.

Here is the Sandbox code to reproduce this problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xljrpxk0yo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mutating the data unknowingly.

Ref to the solution: 
https://twitter.com/kailashvele/status/958336847423270914